# "what" or "which" when no prior range is given

Tags: interrogatives, wh-questions

Which of the following sentences are natural? If the context didn't name a range of hotels, would it be okay to use "which"?

> Location is one of the factors I would consider when deciding on which hotel to stay at.

> Location is one of the factors I would consider when deciding on what hotel to stay at.

Comment: The sentence with "which" sounds natural to me; the one with "what" does not. Whether a list of hotels has been mentioned previously does not change that.

Comment: Do you know why? Learners are typically taught to use "which" only when a list of hotels is mentioned in the prior context.

Comment: The sentence implies that there is some list of hotels under consideration, even theoretically. Contrast "I couldn't decide *what* to eat" when the options are much more varied and no set list of options is implied.

Comment: I find it hard to convice myself that the hotel example implies a set list of hotels. The sentence is a generall statement about what the speaker would do.

Comment: If the list of hotels is not given and if you can change the end of the sentence to **"to stay"** instead of **"hotels to say"** , you can use "_**where**_". just like this, **"I would consider...where to stay"**. with all being said _**what**_ is not a correct choice for these kinds of situations and _**which**_ is the correct idea